# How to configure maven project to deploy both snapshot and releases to Nexus?

Tags: maven, deployment, nexus

How to configure maven project to deploy both snapshot and releases to Nexus?

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>InternalReleases</id>
        <name>Internal Releases</name>
        <url>http://192.168.16.232:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>InternalSnapshots</id>
        <name>Internal Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://192.168.16.232:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

This configuration creates error in Eclipse 3.8 with m2e 1.2

```
Project build error: Non-parseable POM D:\Workspaces\W\Parent\pom.xml: Duplicated tag: 'repository' (position: START_TAG 
 seen ...
```

I want the artifact deployed to the InternalSnapshots repository when the pom's version is suffixed with -SNAPSHOT and deployed to the InternalReleases repository when it is RELEASE. This should happen using the same pom.xml file and executing the same `mvn deploy` command.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to distinguish between the releases and snapshots repository. `<distributionManagement>` only allows one `<repository>` and one `<snapshotRepository>` child.

http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management

Comment: Profiles allow one to use different <distributionManagement> sections.  If you had multiple <repository> and <snapshotRepository> then you could accomplish it with use of different profiles.

Answer (score 30):

Example of `pom.xml` configuration

```
<!-- http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management -->
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>InternalSnapshots</id>
        <name>Internal Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://192.168.16.232:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>InternalReleases</id>
        <name>Internal Releases</name>
        <url>http://192.168.16.232:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Snippets for `.m2/settings.xml` for default Nexus installation

```
<server>   
    <id>thirdparty</id>   
  <username>deployment</username>
  <password>deployment123</password>
</server>
<server>
  <id>InternalReleases</id>
  <username>deployment</username>
  <password>deployment123</password>
 </server>  
<server>
  <id>InternalSnapshots</id>
  <username>deployment</username>
  <password>deployment123</password>
 </server>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do both.

Add the `maven-release-plugin` 2.5.3

Run the following:

```
mvn deploy clean:release release:prepare release:perform
```

Comment: That is nice, but it requires maven and project to be already configured, and that was the salt of the question: how to configure